# How to keep CSS blocks equal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a virtual store where the main page shows the products, this is where the quantity of information in the detail of the product varies, the blocks begin to deform. How could you do to keep the size constant and in any case the text is truncated?

I'm working with MVC 5 and Bootstrap.

```
                <!-- Bloque 1 -->
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <!-- TRAE UNA IMAGEN DE CUALQUIER MANERA-->
                            <img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", new { id = item.ProductoID})" alt="" width="150" height="320" />
                            <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h4 class="pull-right">$@item.PrecioUnitario</h4>
                                    <h4>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Detalle", new { id = item.ProductoID })" class="my-class">
                                            @item.Nombre
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="ratings">
                                @*<p>See more snippets like this online store item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>*@
                                <p>@item.DetallesCorto</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">15 Me gusta</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></span>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <button type="button" class="AddLink btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" href="#" data-id="@item.ProductoID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-cart"></i> Agregar
                                    </button>
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="ratings">
                                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Root") || User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                                {                                        
                                    <p>
                                        <button type="button" class="anchorDetail btn btn-block btn-info btn-xs"
                                                href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@item.ProductoID">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edicion rápida
                                        </button>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <button type="button" class="popupDelete btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs"
                                                href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@item.ProductoID">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Eliminar
                                        </button>
                                    </p>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                } <!-- Cierro Forech -->
            </div>
```

That's how it looks now: [image]

Comment: For the future please upload a fiddle or codepen rather than images, it makes it way easier for us to understand the problem and solve it faster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each `.thumbnail` item and find the max height, then apply a `min-height` to each element matching that max height:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;

    $('.thumbnail').each(function() {
        var height = $(this).height();

        if(height > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = height;
        }
    });

    $('.thumbnail').css('min-height', maxHeight);
});
```

You may need to utilize a delay such as `setTimeout` to ensure everything has been loaded prior to calculating the heights.

Comment: I would create a function (instead of a timeout) and call again on each image load. This is not needed here, because a fixed height and width is set on the img tag.

Comment: I see the benefits of targeting the paragraph for determining height that you presented in your solution. One issue I see would be the that the product titles depending on character length can span multiple lines. Basically each one of those would need to be calculated to get really equal height and alignment.

Comment: Very good point. I would use the same solution there.  I will adjust my answer! Thanks!

Comment: The blocks are now equal in size however they do not fit side by side because it can be?

[link] (https://postimg.org/image/ngtdqjm6h/)

Comment: Excellent answer! Playing a little with the style of the image was solved. Thank you very much for the help!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1 (CSS)**

Set a fixed height on the red paragraph and the title and hide the overflow.

```
.thumbnail .ratings:nth-of-type(1) p {height: 100px; overflow: hidden;}
.thumbnail h4:nth-child(2) {height: 30px; overflow: hidden;}
```

**Solution 2 (jQuery)**

Create a javascript function setting the height equal to the tallest red paragraph and the tallest title.

```
var maxh = 0;
$('.thumbnail .ratings:nth-of-type(1) p').each(function() {
  var h = $(this).height();
  if(h > maxh) maxh = h;
});
$('.thumbnail .ratings:nth-of-type(1) p').css('height', maxh);

var maxh = 0;
$('.thumbnail h4:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
  var h = $(this).height();
  if(h > maxh) maxh = h;
});
$('.thumbnail h4:nth-child(2)').css('height', maxh);
```

You might be tempted to set a fixed height to the thumbnail div. But that will require you to set the rating stars and the green button to `position: absolute; bottom: [amount]px;` to align them properly. I am quite sure that is not compatible with the bootstrap floats and the responsive behaviour of these items.

Comment: Probe both ways, I can not achieve what I want. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Excellent answer! Playing a little with the style of the image was solved. Thank you very much for the help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use rows or set equal height to all boxes with javascript/jquery. Bootstrap uses 12 cols per row so you could modify your code to separate by 4 items per row. Also you only need the smallest device col width if larger ones are same. In your case use col-sm-3 only.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the boxes a set height for example:

```
.box {
     height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I can not or I do not understand how.
This add in html and this in css:

<div class="bloqueProducto"></div>

.bloqueProducto {
    height: 350px;
}